# Topological closure and finitely generated groups and monoids

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, monoid

I would like to ask your expertise on the following question:

Let $G$ be the group of orthogonal matrices of order $n$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of reals, equipped with the topology induced by the Euclidean norm of matrices of $G$.

For any subset $S$ of $G$, denote by $[S]$ the subgroup generated by $S$, and by  $\operatorname{cl}(S)$  the topological closure of $S$.

It is known that, if $S$ is a submonoid of $G$, then $\operatorname{cl}([S])$ is a group and $\operatorname{cl}([S])= \operatorname{cl}(S)$.

**My question is:**

If $\operatorname{cl}([S])$ is finitely generated (as a group), then may one conclude that $S$ is finitely generated (as a monoid)?

Comment: If $A=\operatorname{cl}([S])$ is finitely generated as an  abstract group, then $A$  is countable. Since $A$ is closed in $G$ and $G$ is compact it follows that $A$ is finite. Hence $S$ is also finite. Or is $G$ not necessarily compact?

Comment: Hi Kabenyuk, Thank you for your reply. In my case, G is not necessarily compact

Comment: Hi Nostromo. What do you mean by "$G$ is not necessarily compact"? It sounds like $G$ is the group $O(n)$ of $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices with entries in $\Bbb R$. This group *is* compact by Heine-Borel, since it is a closed and bounded set (discussed in more detail eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447102/orthogonal-matrices-form-a-compact-set)).

Comment: Hi Izaak, thank you a lot for your clarification . You are right. My post on Kabenyuk comment was non sense

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your last reply. I would like to profit of your expertise to ask you 2 related questions. Under the same hypotheses, may I conclude that if the group generated by the submonoid S is finitely generated, then S is finitely generated? Moreover, if S is a free non commutative monoid then the group generated by S is a free non commutative group?